# strongloop/loopback/heroku "inq" operator is working fine on local server but not on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, loopbackjs, strongloop

If i run following without **inq** operator

```
/api/Installations?filter[where][userId]=572d7995a80e6d0300b3f812
```

the result is as follows

```
[
  {
    "appId": "myApp",
    "userId": "572d7995a80e6d0300b3f812",
    "deviceToken": "cjxfuAfldZ4:APA91bFwK6FTqGCgShU4cdk4mPMlFPhevhFTEzsRELUVt5lARYKvhxI8jb55SVCveYf3zjXel3Kb7JrAyoHv6e8Aob8M0SEdepRWrckKliS2Iyh3bWHWH8EIBOp",
    "deviceType": "android",
    "status": "active",
    "id": "572d7996a80e6d0300b3f813",
    "created": "2016-05-07T05:13:58.564Z",
    "modified": "2016-05-07T05:13:58.564Z"
  }
]
```

But now if i run same query with **inq** operator as following

```
/api/Installations?filter={"where": {"userId": {"inq": ["572d7995a80e6d0300b3f812"]}}}
```

it gives me empty result without any error. I have waste many hours but unable to find what could be the reason. Please help me .... Thank you.

Comment: Resolved this by any chance? The question needs much more details. What database do you use on your local and what database do you use on the server. Seems like an id conversion issue.